# Testing convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We're asked to say if the following series converges: $$\sum_{n \textbf{=}1}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}+1}- \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}+1} \right) $$

Here's my approach. $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \ +\infty}  \ \ \sum_{n \textbf{=}1}^k \left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}+1}- \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}+1} \right) $$

$$ =\lim_{k\rightarrow \ +\infty}  \ \ \left(\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n \textbf{=}2}^k \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}+1} -  \sum_{n \textbf{=}2}^{k} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}+1} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+1} \right)$$

$$= \lim_{k\rightarrow \ +\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+1}  \right) $$

$$=1/2$$

Thus, from here I would conclude that the series converges to $1/2$.

The problem is that apperently the series diverges (I've checked on Wolfram Alpha) . Not only do I not understand why my approach is incorrect, but I do not know how to show that this series diverges. I've tried the ratio test as well, which turned out to be non-conclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you took advantage of telescoping, but you forgot about the limit of the leftover term. Notice that
$$\sum_{n=1}^m \left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}+1}- \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}+1} \right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{m+1}{\sqrt{m+1}+1}$$
which implies that
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}+1}- \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}+1} \right) 
&=\lim_{m\to\infty } \sum_{n=1}^m \left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}+1}- \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}+1} \right)\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{m+1}{\sqrt{m+1}+1}\\
&=-\infty
\end{align}\bigg)$$
meaning that the sum diverges.

Comment: Yes, I just saw my mistake... Thank you I got it

Comment: @Skyris Great! If you found this helpful, don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark}$!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:   the $N^{th}$ partial sum is $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n \textbf{=}1}^{N} \left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}+1}- \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}+1} \right) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{N+1}{\sqrt{N+1}+1}\,$.

Comment: I got it, thanks